# Firefox creates extra gap on slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having difficulties with Firefox and drop down menu.
It has of about 200 px gap under the drop down list created by slideToggle.
When inspected, that area is not taken by anything and completely blank/empty.
Chrome displays everything correctly.

Source is here http://stafter.com/demo

I have been fighting this for 2 days already playing around "display" and "margins".

Here is the main code stracture

JQuery CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".plus1").click(function(){
        $(".open1").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".plus2").click(function(){
        $(".open2").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".plus3").click(function(){
        $(".open3").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">

<div id="ul_wrap">

<div class="plus1">
    <ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="open1"></p>
    </div>

<div class="plus2">
<ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="open2"></p>
</div>

<div class="plus3">
    <ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="open3"></p>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto -77px; 
    padding:0;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 77px;
    clear:both;
}
.footer{
    width:100%;
    background: url('../images/bottom_bg.jpg') repeat-x 0 0;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
.container {
    width:800px;
    min-height:400px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:30px;
}
#ul_wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    clear:both;
}
#ul_wrap ul{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left:-20px;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    clear:both;
    height:27px;
}
#ul_wrap li{
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
.one{
    width:40px;
}
.two{
    width:410px;
}

.three{
    width:88px;
}
.open1, .open2, .open3{
    margin:-5px 0 20px 0;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    display:none;
}
```

PLEASE NO COMMENTS LIKE I FORGOT TO CLOSE A TAG OR SMTH, i had to rewrite the entire html code to post it here in short version and shorter names because otherwise it would be 4 page code of css html and javascript. Problem is not in debugging errors in unclosed tags or smth. Source was html validated 1000 times.

Comment: FYI you have two opening body tags in your HTML, and you can combine your document.ready calls.

Comment: For the god sake, if you have checked an actual page you would have noticed there are no TWO body tags, i accidentally wrote it twice here while REWRITING THE WHOLE CODE TO FIT IN on this website.

Comment: Document ready couldn't be combined because its created by the php script one at a time. Thank you for pointing out at obvious, i would appreciate you commenting on the real issue and not about how pretty or ugly my code is. Anything actually useful in comments please?

Answer (score 0):

After playing with margins, display properties and floating and clearing i finally assembled a working structure (for now).

1. The key was to clear all elements and parents containing all floating elements,
2. Then because for some odd reasons slideToggle wasn't working properly with white background (unless you specified height of the hiding element) behind .wrap_ul if it was display:block, only with inline-block.
3. With Display:inline-block it was getting footer floating on the right, no matter clear:both on both items;
4. With specified height, slideToggle wasn't pushing the rest of the sliding elements down below but was overlapping.

Well with all these problems only in Firefox, Chrome never had this flue...
So i posted working code in the last edit, not sure which property got the whole puzzle working which is -> (

- the background behind expanding down slideToggle list,
- footer that is pushed down as well when list is expanded
- not floated footer and no extra gaps or spacing's between drop down list and footer)

Hope you find it usefull